# Unable to connect Time Machine to WD MyCloud EX2 on Sierra

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

I updated to Sierra yesterday and now my Time Machine backups to my WD MyCloud EX2 NAS aren't working any more. Scheduled backups get stuck in "Looking for backup disk..." in Time Machine preferences. Does anyone have ideas on how to resolve this?

Here is what I did to troubleshoot:

1. I am able to access the backup drive over the web interface
   http://wdmycloudex2.local/ and that page mentions my firmware is up
   to date and both the drives are healthy. I can also connect to smb://wdmycloudex2.local and afp://wdmycloudex2.local from Go > Connect to Server in Finder.
2. I went in Time Machine
   preferences and turned it all off.
3. Rebooted WD NAS Confirmed
   power-on test passed by going back to http://wdmycloudex2.local/
4. Went back in Time Machine preferences and tried to add the drive
   back.

Time Machine fails with this error when I try to add the drive back:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Smb isn't supported for time machine. It never was, and could only be hacked to force it to work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to connect to your disk using afp://yourserver.local

If it shows up in your Finder (CMD+K) you should be able to mount it in time machine.

Comment: Yep, this works. Thanks for the tip. Seems like it's an issue with the MyCloud - https://community.wd.com/t/macos-10-12-sierra-time-machine-backup-fails-with-osstatus-error-65-on-a-my-cloud-device-answer-id-14921/179010/2

Comment: @ZachRattner Great, I'm glad this solved your issue!